# OBJ loader acting oddly

Tags: c++, directx-11

My object reader is meant to read the vertices, normals texture coordinates values from an obj file and then it is meant to read the faces values and retrieve the corresponding data from the vectors of vertices,normals and textures. The problem I have is that sometimes it seems to ignore taking -1 away from the value it does read:

```
using namespace std;

class Model
{

string name;

int verticesAmount;
int indicesAmount;
int normalAmount;
int textureAmount;

vector<XMFLOAT3> vertices;
vector<short> indices;
vector<SimpleVertex> simplevertex;
vector<XMFLOAT3> normals;
vector<XMFLOAT3> textures;

public:
    Model(const string OBJname)
    {
LoadOBJ(OBJname);
    }

 vector<XMFLOAT3> GetVertices()
 {

     return vertices;
 }

 vector<SimpleVertex> GetVertexData()
 {
     return simplevertex;
 }

 vector<short> GetIndices()
 {

     return indices;
 }

 int GetNumberOfVertices()
 {
     return simplevertex.size();
 }

  int GetNumberOfIndices()
 {
     return indices.size();
 }

void LoadOBJ(const string fileName)
{
    verticesAmount = 0;
    indicesAmount = 0;
    normalAmount = 0;
    textureAmount = 0;

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(fileName.c_str());


    if (!inFile.good())
    {
        cerr  << "Can't open file" << fileName << endl; // checks if you can open the file or not
    }
    else cout<<fileName<< " opened successfully \n";

    string line;
    while(!inFile.eof())
    {

        inFile >> line;
        XMFLOAT3 temp;
            if (line[0] =='v')
            {
                if (line.length() >1)
                {
                    if(line[1] == 'n')
                    {
                        inFile >> temp.x;
                        inFile >> temp.y;
                        inFile >> temp.z;
                        normals.push_back(temp);
                        normalAmount++;
                    }
                    else if (line[1] == 't')
                    {
                        inFile >> temp.x;
                        inFile >> temp.y;
                        inFile >> temp.z;
                        textures.push_back(temp);
                        textureAmount++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    inFile >> temp.x;
                    inFile >> temp.y;
                    inFile >> temp.z;
                    vertices.push_back(temp);
                    indicesAmount++;
                }
            }
            else if (line[0] == 'f')
            {
                SimpleVertex temp2;
                char bin;
                int tempindice;

                inFile >> tempindice;                           // inputs data
                indices.push_back(tempindice-1);
                temp2.Pos.x = vertices[(tempindice-1)].x;
                inFile >> bin;                                  // gets rid of the /
                inFile >> tempindice;                           // inputs data
                temp2.Texture.x = textures[(tempindice-1)].x;
                inFile >> bin;                                  // gets rid of the /
                inFile >> tempindice;                           // inputs data
                temp2.Normal.x = normals[(tempindice-1)].x;

                inFile >> tempindice;                           // inputs data
                indices.push_back(tempindice-1);
                temp2.Pos.y = vertices[(tempindice-1)].y;
                inFile >> bin;                                  // gets rid of the /
                inFile >> tempindice;                           // inputs data
                temp2.Texture.y = textures[(tempindice-1)].y;
                inFile >> bin;                                  // gets rid of the /
                inFile >> tempindice;                           // inputs data
                temp2.Normal.y = normals[(tempindice-1)].y;

                inFile >> tempindice;                           // inputs data
                indices.push_back(tempindice);
                temp2.Pos.z = vertices[(tempindice-1)].z;
                inFile >> bin;                                  // gets rid of the /
                inFile >> tempindice;                           // inputs data
                temp2.Texture.z = textures[(tempindice-1)].z;
                inFile >> bin;                                  // gets rid of the /
                inFile >> tempindice;                           // inputs data
                temp2.Normal.z = normals[(tempindice-1)].z;

                simplevertex.push_back(temp2);
                indicesAmount++;
            }
            else
            {
                inFile.ignore(1000,'\n');
            }
        }

    inFile.close();

}
```

};

this is the whole model class that I made and it is the loadOBj function I have the problem with. here is the SimpleVertex Structure that it uses:

```
struct SimpleVertex
{
    XMFLOAT3 Pos;
    XMFLOAT3 Normal;
    XMFLOAT3 Texture;
};
```

I am not sure why it is doing this and eve my lectures seem perplexed.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it seems to ignor taking -1 away from the value it reads in sometimes'? Show us some sample input, and say how you expect it to be read, and how you see it being read instead. Computers never ignore what you tell them to do so the problem is that you aren't telling it correctly. We need a bit more detail to know what your expectations are.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yq3zvn7cvpphi4d/testCube2.obj

that is the object file i am trying to read from. by ignoring the -1 i mean in the lines like
 temp2.Texture.x = textures[(tempindice-1)].x;
when it reads in the first line of the "f" part of the file, it should -1 form the value it gets, then go and get the value from the vector at that part. but it sometimes reads the next line instead.

for example with the first value it reads -10.0916 0.0000 10.4466 in to the position x,y and z. but it reads in -10.0916 0.0000 -10.1075
 instead, which is the 2nd line and not the first.

hope thatsok

Comment: OK got it, let me think about it

Comment: I've tested your code but I can't see anything wrong with it. Instead I think you have it wrong in your expectations. For instance the first position is -10.0916 0.0000 -10.1075 like you say but that is what you would expect from the input which is 1/1/1 2/2/1 3/3/1. The position indices are the first in each triple **1** /1/1 **2** /2/1 **3** /3/1. So I would expect the position to have the first X value from vertices, the second Y value and the third Z value, and that is -10.0916 0.0000 -10.1075 as expected. I wonder if you have got yourself confsued about the order of the indices.

Comment: hmm possibly, when i draw the object it is mishapen. i am not sure how to restructer it store it in the right order..

Comment: Before you go any further you should improve your loader a lot more. You are always assuming it will have texture and normal coordinate which is not true. You are also assuming that vertices will be one-to-one with normal coordinates and texture coordinates, which is also not true. I also agree with @john, I think you got the indices mixed up.